# eclipse vs cmd maven repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I am working on a project where there is quite a lot of dependencies loaded. I am using a specific settings.xml file which is pointing specific direction for the m2 repository. It set in eclipse preferences for maven to use this settings file and also as a environment variable to use this settings file.

Now, the scenario that I am no sure what happens is:

2. there was a change in the code that requires an update of the dependencies
3. you are using the Maven -> Update project... option from project context menu in eclipse, or using the Maven build with the Update snapshots option checked
4. Dependencies are downloaded and in eclipse you can see that the code is building again.
5. And here is the part that I do not understand, now I am trying to run simply "mvn clean install" on the specific project but it is not building, I need to use the -U option and when the dependencies are downloaded, then the build is success.

I know that this is long scenario and for someone probably a tl;dr but would be very grateful if someone could explain it to me why there is a need to download the dependencies double.

Comment: Have you looked up what exactly happens in your local repository (.mv/repository)? Do both Eclipse and mvn download the jars to the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the Eclipse plugin uses an *embedded maven* that is different than the installed in your operating system. If you use custom settings, you must configure both.

- In Eclipse, you can go to `Window > Preferences`, and look for `Maven > Installation`. You may check there the maven you are using. There is a default `EMBEDDED` maven. You can use a button to `Add..` others.
- In `Window > Preferences`, and look for `Maven > User Settings` to define your `settings.xml` file.
- For external (typical) maven installations, the [`settings.xml` file](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) is located in your home directory.

To avoid double configurations (and repositories), I think you can

1. Configure Eclipse to use the same `settings.xml`, or
2. [Configure Eclipse to use an external maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/usage.html#Maven_as_an_external_tool).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. But I have this configuration. This is the whole point of my issue. Even though eclipse and cmd maven uses the same settings.xml it behaves like two separate installations of maven.

Comment: Are you using maven as an external tool in Eclipse ?

Comment: no, I am using the first aproach, so that my command line maven ( if you can say so) and the one in eclipse uses the same settings.xml file which is pointing specific local repository location

Comment: @Jaimie , ok, I might misunderstood you, I can see that in my eclipse this maven installation is marked as external. But at the end, this just makes that it points to the same settings file, event in the Eclipse Window->Preferences->Maven->User settings I can see a correct path to the Local repository folder

Comment: If both mavens point to the same settings or if you use the same maven, I think they must work. -- Probably, it is an Eclipse bug. Apparently, you [must update and re-index the maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868945/4433204) after changing the `settings.xml` in the Eclipse.

Comment: the re-index options did not make any change, somehow it behaves like two separate instances of maven. guess I will have to live with that